# Herencia en PyQt desde módulo externo

Tags: python, python-3.x, herencia, pyqt4

Tengo una ventana de `PyQt4` con dos listas `QListWidget` donde quiero poder intercambiar los items entre ellas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer más limpio el código he creado la clase `PasaItems` en un módulo a parte:

**pasaitems.py**

```
class PasaItems:
    """Intercambio de items entre listas QListWidget."""

    def __init__(self, l1, l2):

        self.lst_1 = l1  # Lista 1.
        self.lst_2 = l2  # Lista 2.

    def pasa_items(self):  # Pasa items de la lista lst_1 a la lista lst_2.

        for item in self.lst_1.selectedItems():  # Añade items a lst_2.

            self.lst_2.addItem(item.text())

        for SelectedItem in self.lst_1.selectedItems():  # Elimina items de lst_1.

            self.lst_1.takeItem(self.lst_1.row(SelectedItem))

        self.lst_2.sortItems()  # Ordena items en lst_2.

    def pasa_todos_items(self):  # Pasa todos los items de la lista lst_1 a la lista lst_2.

        for index in range(self.lst_1.count()):  # Añade items a lst_2.

            index = self.lst_1.item(index).text()
            self.lst_2.addItem(index)

        self.lst_2.sortItems()  # Ordena items en lst_2.
        self.lst_1.clear()  # Elimina items de lst_1.
```

Ahora quiero importar la clase en el código donde se ejecuta el programa:

**hades_C.pyw**

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from qtdesigner.hades_C import *
from clases.pasaitems import PasaItems

class Window(PasaItems, QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, l1, l2, parent=None):

        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        PasaItems.__init__(self, l1, l2)

        self.lst_archivos_ruta = self.ui.listWidget_archivos_ruta
        self.lst_archivos_implantacion = self.ui.listWidget_archivos_implantacion

        # Selecciona casos de carga.
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_selecciona_cc, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.selecciona_cc)

    def selecciona_cc(self):

        PasaItems.pasa_items(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = Window()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El mensaje de error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
  File "C:/Python/Apps/Hades/Hades_C/hades_C.pyw", line 231, in <module>
    myapp = Window()

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'l1' and 'l2'
```

He intentado seguir la lógica que aparece en cualquier tutorial sobre herencias de clases, pero no me funciona con `PyQt4`.

---

**Revisión de `hades_C.py` según respuesta de FJSevilla**

**2018.05.18**

**hades_c_1.py**

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from qtdesigner.hades_C import *
from clases.pasaitems import PasaItems


class Window(PasaItems, QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.lst_archivos_ruta = self.ui.listWidget_archivos_ruta
        self.lst_archivos_implantacion = self.ui.listWidget_archivos_implantacion
        self.btn_selecciona_cc = self.ui.pushButton_selecciona_cc

        self.btn_selecciona_cc.clicked.connect(self.selecciona_cc)

    def selecciona_cc(self):

        PasaItems(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo).pasa_items()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

- Tu inicializar (`def __init__(self, l1, l2, parent=None)`) de `Window` recibe dos argumentos obligatorios (`l1` y `l2`), los cuales no los pasas al instanciar (`myapp = Window()`). No comprendo que pretendes con esto, dado que los widgets QList los defines dentro de la clase Window (a través de `Ui_MainWindow`). Esto es lo que causa el error que muestras y que  es bastante explícito.
- Tu clase hereda de `PasaItems` y luego intenta crear una instancia de la misma clase. No se si quieres usar herencia o composición a la hora de usar la clase junto a `Window`, ambas no tiene mucho sentido.
- Tu clase `Window` hereda de `QMainWindow` pero no llamas a su inicializador, llamas al de `QDialog`, lo cual no tiene sentido en principio. En vez de:

  ```
  QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
  ```

  Deberías hacer:

  ```
  QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
  ```
- Cuando intentas usar `PasaItems.pasa_items`  en el método `selecciona_cc` con:

  ```
  PasaItems.pasa_items(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo)
  ```

  Lo haces incorrectamente, el método `pasa_items` no recibe parámetros, además es un método de instancia y en ningún momento instancias la clase. En todo caso debes hacer:

  ```
  PasaItems(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo).pasa_items()
  ```

  Donde `PasaItems(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo)` crea una instancia de la clase usando su inicializador que es el que recibe las instancias de los `QList`: `def __init__(self, l1, l2)`. Posteriormente se llama al método de instacia `pasa_items()`. Es lo mismo que hacer:

  ```
  pi_inst = `PasaItems(self.lst_casos_carga, self.lst_casos_carga_grupo)`
  pi_inst.pasa_items()
  ```
- `self.btn_selecciona_cc` no existe en tu clase `Window`. Usas composición para usar los widgets definidos en `Ui_MainWindow`, no herencia. Por tanto los widgets pertenecen a la intancia de `Ui_MainWindow` (`self.ui`) no a las instancias de `Window` (`self`) debes usar `self.ui.btn_selecciona_cc`.

Esto no es un error en si, pero a partir de la versión 4.5 de PyQt4 y en PyQt5 se estableció una [nueva sintaxis para la conexión de signals y slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), por lo que en vez de:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_selecciona_cc, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.selecciona_cc)
```

haces:

```
self.btn_selecciona_cc.clicked.connect(self.selecciona_cc)
```

Comment: Al ver tu respuesta @FJSevilla me he asustado, pero con tus comentarios me ha sido bastante fácil corregir los errores. Añado una revisión del código `hades_C.py` tal como me funciona.
Con respecto tu último punto sobre `self.btn_selecciona_cc` ha sido un error al copiar el código. No copié todo para presentar únicamente las líneas donde suponía que podía estar el problema, y me deje esa.
Un saludo.